# Netbeans color scheme settings

Tags: netbeans, colors, editor, themes, look-and-feel

Trying to create Sublime Text environment in Netbeans IDE.

The screen below is before moving cursor into any "path"

[image]

And after

[image]

As you see, bg color of multiple instances changed.

The problem is. How can I change this color? Can't find in settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using NetBeans on Windows or Linux or Mac? On Mac, you can go to Netbeans --> Preferences --> Fonts and Colors --> Highlighting. Not sure where the equivalent menu is on Windows or Linux.

**EDIT**

Go to NetBeans --> Preferences --> Fonts and Colors --> Syntax.
Select your language from the drop-down list and then select the `Mark Occurrences` category, that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I already found this "Highlighting". http://prntscr.com/5o1em which of theese categories ?

Comment: It's in NetBeans --> Preferences --> Fonts and Colors --> Syntax. Select your language and then the `Mark Occurrences` item from the list.

Comment: for linux it was in netbeans > tools > option > fonts and color > highlighting